# Menu does not appear while opening my site

Tags: routes

management menu such as add content type,module ,configuration does not appear in my site.
So how can I solve it.

Comment: Are you logged in as the admin user?

Comment: Try logging in with yoursitename/?q=user. If you're already logged in...have you typed yoursitename/admin in your browser address bar to see if that brings it back for you?

Comment: Once you're in there you'll want to go to modules and make sure to re-enable 'toolbar'.

Answer (score 0):

Please login through admin credentials. Check module permissions for Toolbar for authenticated users. Check that if it is unchecked. Try flushing drupal cache.

Once you see the toolbar. You can install admin_menu for better administration menu.

https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_menu